# Play array of sounds after a delay

Tags: javascript, settimeout

need help here. So I want to loop through an array of sounds so that it plays after a delay of say 1000ms. How do I achieve that? I tried this but it runs all the sounds at once:

Link for the Simon game app that I am trying to build using Vanilla JS: https://codesandbox.io/s/simongame-fcc-4thbk

```
colorArray.forEach(color => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    color.play();
  }, 1000)
});
```

Comment: You want each of the sounds to play but space them 1000ms apart, right?

Comment: Increment delay, so that not all sounds plays at same time

Comment: @VLAZ yes, play each sound 1000ms apart.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already iterating over an array, that makes the index of each item available in each iteration. You can use that to calculate a higher timeout for each iteration step. Note that this probably will lead to overlapping sound play (assuming the sounds have a duration of 1s) as the `setTimeout` method only gurantees a minimum delay which you specify. It does not guarantee when your code will run exactly.

```js
colorArray.forEach((color, index) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    color.play();
  }, 1000*++index)
});
```

Comment: What I fail to understand is why ```color.play();``` is not running every 1 second?

Comment: Because all the timeouts will be set up synchronously, which means you set up `n` timeouts to all execute with 1000ms minimum delay, where `n` is the length of the `colorArray`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a growing increment to the delay between sounds, which will space out *playing* the sounds 1000ms apart:

```
colorArray.forEach((color, index) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    color.play();
  }, 1000 * (index + 1))
//           ^^^^^^^^^ delay more for each following element
});
```

However, you might run into a problem if each sound is bigger than the base delay. So, if you have a 2 second sound clip, that would play and halfway through it, the next one would play, too. So, you might want to wait for the first to finish *and* wait for 1000ms before playing the next one. If you are using a `HTMLMediaElement`, then you can listen for the [`ended` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/ended_event) and when one finishes, play the next one:

```
//set the event listeners
colorArray
  .reduce((lastColor, currentColor) => {
    lastColor.addEventListener("ended", () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        currentColor.play();
      }, 1000)
    })
    return currentColor;
  });

//run the first playback which will then run the next one
colorArray[0].play()
```

A minor variation is to use `.reduceRight` to iterate through the events backwards. You can do that:

```
//set the event listeners
colorArray
  .reduceRight((lastColor, currentColor) => {
    currentColor.addEventListener("ended", () => { // <------------
      setTimeout(() => {  //  current and last are swapped here   |
        lastColor.play(); //<--------------------------------------
      }, 1000)
    })
    return currentColor;
  })
  .play(); //run the first playback which will then run the next one
```

```js
function playAll() {
  let soundsArray = [...document.querySelectorAll("audio")];

  soundsArray.forEach((sound, index) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("waiting for 1 second before playing");
      sound.play();
    }, 1000 * (index + 1));
  });
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", playAll)
```

```html
<audio src="http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/alien_shoot.wav" controls="controls"></audio>
<audio src="http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/explosion_02.wav" controls="controls"></audio>
<audio src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-demos/pyman_assets/intromusic.ogg" controls="controls"></audio>
<audio src="http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/explosion%2001.wav" controls="controls"></audio>
<br/>
<button>Play All</button>
```

And here is how these two differ - the third sound clip in particular will overlap with the fourth one using the first method but not the second one:

```js
function playAll() {
  let soundsArray = [...document.querySelectorAll("audio")];

  soundsArray
    .reduceRight((lastSound, currentSound) => {
      currentSound.addEventListener("ended", () => {
        console.log("waiting for 1 second after playing");
        setTimeout(() => {
          lastSound.play();
        }, 1000)
      });
      return currentSound;
    })
    .play()
}
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", playAll)
```

```html
<audio src="http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/alien_shoot.wav" controls="controls"></audio>
<audio src="http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/explosion_02.wav" controls="controls"></audio>
<audio src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-demos/pyman_assets/intromusic.ogg" controls="controls"></audio>
<audio src="http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/explosion%2001.wav" controls="controls"></audio>
<br/>
<button>Play All</button>
```

I've used sounds from [here](https://simpleguics2pygame.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_static/links/snd_links.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
var counter = 1;
colorArray.forEach(color => { setTimeout(() => { color.play(); },counter++*1000) });
```

This increments the delay by 1000 for each element in the `colorArray`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options. One is to schedule all sounds ahead of time.

```
colorArray.forEach((color, i) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    color.play();
  }, 1000 * (i + 1))
});
```

Another is to use `setInterval()`. In theory, this should lead to more consistent timings.

```
let index = 0;

const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
 if (index < colorArray.length)
   colorArray[index++].play();
 else
   clearInterval(intervalId)
}, 1000)
```

`setInterval()` calls a callback at a specified interval. It's an inbuilt method by the javascript runtime to perform work at a set pace.

Note: The javascript standard does not guarantee that the timings will be accurate on either of these methods, but `setInterval` should be more performant as it only schedules one callback with the runtime.